# RedirectToAction ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I currently read Freeman's book ASP .NET MVC 4 and do a web application. So, there is a controller named "Cart" with method "AddToCart" and a View. In the view we have such code:

```
@model SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product

<div class="item">
    <h3>@Model.Name</h3>
    @Model.Description
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart"))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductID)
        @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
        <input type="submit" value="+ Add to cart" />
    }

    <h4>@Model.Price.ToString("c")</h4>
</div>
```

and the method's of the controller code:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl)
{
   Product product = repository.Products
      .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
   if (product != null)
   {
      cart.AddItem(product, 1);
   }
   return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
}
```

The code compiles very good, but I have here some questions.

1) If you put a breakpoint on the line:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
```

you'll see that returnUrl has value "**/**". How? Where did he get it?

2) What are these lines of code doing, because there is no information in the book about it.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductID)
@Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer Your second question first.
**@Html** has a set of helpers generating html.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductID)
```

will output something like: `<input type="hidden" name="ProductID" value="1" />`

```
@Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
```

will output something like: `<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value"/" />`

Now look at AddToCart method signature:

`AddToCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl)`

Values of these hidden inputs but will be included in the form while posting to AddToCart action and model binding will assign them to `productId` and `returnUrl` arguments accordingly.

Next to answer first question:

[Request.Url.PathAndQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.uri.pathandquery) property returns absolute path of request with query parameters. So if you came to AddToCart view from Index view then `returnUrl` will be "/", 
because Your Index view is a root of Your webapp, so to speak. It all comes down how routing is configured in Your application.

For more information go watch these tutorials: [Controllers and Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing)

Comment: Thanks a lot... I found the answer on my question!

Answer (score 0):

Index is a name that MVC "assumes" so if you go to the index view you won't see

```
/index
```

in the url.  just /

the 2 hidden fields that you showed are an MVC was of creating

```
<input type="hidden" ...
```

if is a way to store information that you need on your view for passing back to the controller through a post back or ajax call

Answer (score 0):

There is the parameter used by your method controller, the hidden fields is the input fied used to send the paramenters to your server side script

```
"returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery
```

> Request.Url.PathAndQuery

will be used by RedirectToAction to establish where to send you

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
```

> p.ProductID

to manage what you want add to chart